# java class to call back activity when location updates

Tags: java, android, location

I found this class I'd like to use to obtain location updates but I'm trying to find out how to implement callbacks to the activity when location updates.
Do I use some callback or other type of method to implement this?

note I got the code from  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

```
GPSTracker.java
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Rephrase your question and post relevant code to make clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you should add a callback method like that :

```
public GPSTracker(Context context, Activity calleractivity) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();

  this.calleractivity=calleractivity
}
```

And your update method would be something like

```
 public void update(){
       calleractivity.getback();
    }
```

And in your activity :

```
gps = new GPSTracker(Context context, this);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks I almost understand this , I assume I need some method defined in my Activity to process callback?

Comment: Just one method (like getBack() in my example ) to be called in your Activity

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- Services run on the UI thread by default. This class might block your UI if getting location from a particular source takes a long time. How often do you need updates? You could run a timer to send out requests to an IntentService to get GPS info.
- If you really do need GPS "tracking", then you're doing the right thing, but remember that GPS drains the battery quickly.
- The best way to communicate from one Android component to another is to use a BroadcastReceiver. This provides a clear, straightforward callback that can handle more than one "message" from various components.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used to get location using your GPSTracker class, Paste your code on your activity onCreate method for testing purpose. Yes it will block your UI thread for now but you will get the location. After that you can read about using [Service](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) in Android to get a better idea.

```
            LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {
                @Override
                public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                    Log.d("Activity","In gotLocation Listener");
                    boolean hasAddedQr = false;
                    if(hasAddedQr){
                        return;
                    }
                    hasAddedQr = true;
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.d("Activity","Got the location");

                        // Got the location!
                        try {

                            double lati = location.getLatitude();
                            double longi = location.getLongitude();

                            text.setText("Got Location: La="+lati+", Lo="+longi);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                    } else {
                        GetLocation.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                text.setText("Location was returned null");

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            GPSTracker myLocation = new GPSTracker();
            boolean isEnabled = myLocation.getLocation(GetLocation.this, locationResult);
            if(!isEnabled){
                Log.d("Activity", "LOCATION SERVICES WERE NOT ENABLED");
                text.setText("Location service not available");
                getLocationBtn.setEnabled(true);

            }
            else{
                Log.d("Activity", "LOCATION SERVICES ENABLED");

            }
```